# GROUP BY total order quantity

Tags: sql-server, count, sum

we're trying to make our table add together all values in column 2 (QtyComp - an expression column of **qtyorder * totalqty** basically), where they have the same ItemNo (column 1).

So, we currently get the below:

```
ItemNo          QtyComp
7441            3
7441            1
7441            5
```

What we want is it to see the SUM of the column QTYComp to give this result:

```
ItemNo          QtyCom
7441            9
```

Our code is below; I've bolded the part that we need it to sum the results of:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
                         workorderdetails.qtycomplete * 
                         ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot AS QtyComp 
FROM   dbo.workorderdetails AS WorkOrderDetails 
       INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecfullstruc AS ItemSpecFullStruc_2 
               ON ItemSpecFullStruc_2.rootitemspecid = 
                  workorderdetails.itemspecid 
       INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecs AS ItemSpecs_2 
               ON ItemSpecs_2.itemspecid = ItemSpecFullStruc_2.childitemspecid 
       INNER JOIN dbo.workorder AS WorkOrder_1 
               ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = workorderdetails.workorderid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tobescheduled_completed 
                    ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = 
                       dbo.tobescheduled_completed.workorderid 
WHERE ( workorderdetails.completed = 1 ) 
      AND ( workorderdetails.compdate > Getdate() - 42 ) 
GROUP  BY ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
          workorderdetails.qtyordered, 
          ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot, 
          workorderdetails.[lineno], 
          workorderdetails.qtycomplete, 
          workorderdetails.compdate, 
          workorderdetails.qtycomplete * ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot
```

We would really appreciate some ideas!

Thanks, 
Trish

Comment: Remove columns from the `GROUP BY` until you get what you want.

Comment: duplicated post 15hours ago. :D

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh it is mysql

Comment: Wait a minute, are you sure about MySQL? That query looks more like MS SQL Server.

Comment: You typically group by the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions. I.e. in your case `group by ItemSpecs_2.itemno`.

Comment: So you're using MySQL 8.0??

Comment: SQL Server. @Strawberry

Comment: So it's not MySQL then. :-(

Answer (score 0):

assuming your current code gives you correct calculations, the lazy answer would be to write it as a CTE and then sum it, but this may result in sub optimal table scans - fine if it's just adhoc.

```
with mytemp as (
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
                         workorderdetails.qtycomplete * 
                         ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot AS QtyComp 
FROM   dbo.workorderdetails AS WorkOrderDetails 
       INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecfullstruc AS ItemSpecFullStruc_2 
               ON ItemSpecFullStruc_2.rootitemspecid = 
                  workorderdetails.itemspecid 
       INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecs AS ItemSpecs_2 
               ON ItemSpecs_2.itemspecid = ItemSpecFullStruc_2.childitemspecid 
       INNER JOIN dbo.workorder AS WorkOrder_1 
               ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = workorderdetails.workorderid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tobescheduled_completed 
                    ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = 
                       dbo.tobescheduled_completed.workorderid 
WHERE ( workorderdetails.completed = 1 ) 
      AND ( workorderdetails.compdate > Getdate() - 42 ) 
GROUP  BY ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
          workorderdetails.qtyordered, 
          ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot, 
          workorderdetails.[lineno], 
          workorderdetails.qtycomplete, 
          workorderdetails.compdate, 
          workorderdetails.qtycomplete * ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot
)

select
itemno
,sum(QtyComp) as QtyComp
from mytemp
group by itemno
```

Comment: Can i place this as a derived table?

Comment: @TrishFernandez yes, the execution plans will be the same.

Comment: Barker, can you assist me as I am getting a syntax error? :(

Comment: Hi Trish, before trying my solution, ensure your SQL statement executes. If it does, ensure your variable names are correctly written in my CTE example (may be case sensitive?)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum these column, simply add a sum() syntax as follows:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
                         sum(workorderdetails.qtycomplete * 
                         ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot) AS QtyComp 
FROM   dbo.workorderdetails AS WorkOrderDetails 
       INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecfullstruc AS ItemSpecFullStruc_2 
               ON ItemSpecFullStruc_2.rootitemspecid = 
                  workorderdetails.itemspecid 
       INNER JOIN dbo.itemspecs AS ItemSpecs_2 
               ON ItemSpecs_2.itemspecid = ItemSpecFullStruc_2.childitemspecid 
       INNER JOIN dbo.workorder AS WorkOrder_1 
               ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = workorderdetails.workorderid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tobescheduled_completed 
                    ON WorkOrder_1.workorderid = 
                       dbo.tobescheduled_completed.workorderid 
WHERE ( workorderdetails.completed = 1 ) 
      AND ( workorderdetails.compdate > Getdate() - 42 ) 
GROUP  BY ItemSpecs_2.itemno, 
          workorderdetails.qtyordered, 
          ItemSpecFullStruc_2.totalqtyperroot, 
          workorderdetails.[lineno], 
          workorderdetails.qtycomplete, 
          workorderdetails.compdate
```

Also, you need to delete from group by that column.

For getting the desired result, set a GROUP BY only by ItemSpecs_2.itemno